# Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #8 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column

Tags: mysql, apache, cakephp

i tried the CakePHP 3.x "Bookmaker Tutorial" and i followed the instruction step by step. Unfortunately, at the end of the first chapter i get the attached error:

```
Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #8 of SELECT list
is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'wis.Tags.id' which is not
functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with 
sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

Furthermore, i get the information to check my "BookmarksTags" table but i do not have to creat one before. I little bit confused.

```
Please try correcting the issue for the following table aliases:

BookmarksTags
```

I already google my problem and i found information to update the "my.cnf" with a extra line. i already try but nothing happed. I also check the spelling and downloaded the "bookmarker-tutorial" from github but i still get this error above.

I use MySQL 5.7.11 and PHP 5.6.14.

Answer (score 25):

This is a new thing in MySQL 5.7 and is a warning that your query is ambiguous.

Consider the following table:

```
id    |   name    |   age    |   points
--------------------------------------------
1         Bob         21         1
2         James       14         1
3         Bob         21         3
4         James       14         2
5         Casey       17         3
```

If you did the following query:

```
SELECT name, age, SUM(points) FROM scores GROUP BY name
```

Then the `name` column is used for grouping. Note that `age` may have multiple values, so it's "non-aggregated". You need to do something to collapse down those values.

The behaviour in 5.6 and previous was to just pick the first one depending on sort order, though this was sometimes unpredictable and would fail. In 5.7 they're preventing you from doing it in the first place.

The solution here is to group on that as well, or to apply an aggregate operator like `MIN()` to it.

Comment: Is there a way to just get the first one regardless of the sort order?

Comment: @rotaercz Without sorting the very concept of "first" is meaningless.

Comment: What I mean is, is there a way to get the rows regardless? GROUP BY used to work fine for what I had before MySQL 5.7. It didn't deal with the ambiguity and in many circumstances it didn't matter depending on what was being retrieved.

Comment: @rotaercz That's because in older versions of MySQL the first row was chosen arbitrarily which lead to unpredictable results. In 5.7 they've fixed this and made MySQL like other SQL databases with having a concern for consistency.

Comment: Is there no way to get it arbitrarily now?

Comment: `ORDER BY RAND()` if you really don't care. At least you're declaring you're utterly unconcerned with consistency.

Answer (score 18):

I'm using Laravel 5.4 and facing same problem.
I try to set `strict` into `false` on `config/database.php` and it works.

```
'connections' => [
    'mysql' => [
        'strict' => false,
    ]
]
```

However it's better to edit sql query than suppress it's warning.

Answer (score 4):

This may be the issue related to newer version of MySQL as you said you are using MySQL 5.7.11
So to solve this issue for all your sites see this

https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/12084/getting-this-sql-error-group-by-incompatible-with-sql-mode-only-full-group-by/13662#13662

the answer by community to add the line below

```
sql_mode=STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

in /etc/mysql/my.cnf file & saving it; and after restarting the server

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

Would do the work

Answer (score 3):

Just stumbled on the same problem.
A simple way to make the tutorial "work" without changing the query could be to reset `sql_mode` in `config/app.php` :

```
'Datasources' => [
    'default' => [
        'className' => 'Cake\Database\Connection',
        'driver' => 'Cake\Database\Driver\Mysql',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => 'localhost',
        ...
        'init' => ["SET sql_mode = ''"],
    ],
```

While this should makes things work, it is probably not recommended in real life cases.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to tadman's comment, for tutorial you are following, you should distinct your sql select query by both Bookmarks.id and BookmarksTags.tag_id, instead of just Bookmarks.id

To do that, in BookmarksTable.php file, line

```
->distinct(['Bookmarks.id'])
```

should look like

```
->distinct(['Bookmarks.id', 'BookmarksTags.tag_id'])
```