# Laravel grouping and ordering database results

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-6

Say I have the following table...

```
+----+---------------------+---------+---------------------+
| id | slug                | version | created_at          |
+----+---------------------+---------+---------------------+
| 1  | url-friendly-string | 1.0.0   | 2020-01-19 01:00:00 |
+----+---------------------+---------+---------------------+
| 2  | url-friendly-string | 1.0.0   | 2020-01-19 02:00:00 |
+----+---------------------+---------+---------------------+
| 3  | url-friendly-string | 1.0.1   | 2020-01-20 00:00:00 |
+----+---------------------+---------+---------------------+
| 4  | another             | 0.0.1   | 2020-01-20 00:30:00 |
+----+---------------------+---------+---------------------+
| 5  | another             | 0.0.2   | 2020-01-20 01:00:00 |
+----+---------------------+---------+---------------------+
```

There can be multiple entries with the same `slug` and `version` and I want to get the latest, highest version of each item grouped by `slug`. For example, the end result would look somewhat like...

```php
$collection = Array(
    Object(
        'slug' => 'another',
        'version' => '0.0.2',
        'created_at' => '2020-01-20 01:00:00'
    ),
    Object(
        'slug' => 'url-friendly-string',
        'version' => '1.0.1',
        'created_at' => '2020-01-20 00:00:00'
    )
)
```

I've tried the following...

**1.**

```php
$collection = auth()->user()
    ->items()
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
    ->orderBy('version', 'desc')
    ->groupBy('slug', 'version')
    ->get();
```

Which produces:

> Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column

A good answer about this error can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36230200/3804924

**2.**

```php
$collection = auth()->user()
    ->items()
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
    ->orderBy('version', 'desc')
    ->get()
    ->groupBy('slug', 'version')
    ->map(function($group) {
        return $group->first();
    });
```

Which kind of works but can produce incorrect ordering.

---

How can I get to where I need to be?

This is a new project so destructing tables etc is not an issue.

Comment: What do you mean by incorrect ordering?

Answer (score 0):

You can sort table first through sub query, try this:

```php
$subSql = DB::table('my_table')->orderBy('version', 'desc')->toSql();

$result = DB::table( DB::raw("({$subSql}) as subQuery") )
    ->groupBy('slug')
    ->get();
```